# Devise Error Messages on another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Rails 4.2.0, Devise 3.4.1

I am using Devise signup form in another controller. I want to show the error messages on the same page but can't find my way. Here is the code

```
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <%= form_for(:user, url: registration_path(:user)) do |f| %>


    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :email %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <% if @validatable %>
            <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
            <% end %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
          </div>

          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
          </div>
    <% end %>
```

This code

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

throws an error

```
NameError in StaticPages#home -undefined local variable or method `resource'
```

I do not need the code devise_error_messages! since I already have the following in my Layout

```
<div class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></div>
<div class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></div>
```

Also, I have successfully redirected the user to a custom page after successful signup. However, when the signup fails, the path redirects to localhost/users.

I want to show the error message on the same page. I tried using JSON but it does not go through. Any idea where am I making a mistake?